# Trouble Navigating Dynamic Website with Web Scraper

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm currently facing an issue while building a web scraper. My goal is to extract specific tables from a dynamic website. Initially, I encountered no problems in extracting the first set of content. However, I'm struggling with navigating to subsequent tables due to various issues with my solutions.

Upon opening the website, I find myself at the default value "Aachen". What I need help with is figuring out how to navigate to the page with value "Aalen" (to simulate the "click") to access the next table.  Furthermore, I aim to create a loop to iterate through all the other values.

I suspect that the main challenge lies in locating the value that needs to be changed, as it is relatively deep within the website's hierarchy (see image attached).

[image: Hirachy of the Webpage]

And here is my code for reading the initial content:

```
import urllib.request
import requests

from selenium import webdriver
import time

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import re
import spacy
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display


def split_second_element_last_letter(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for item in lst:
        if len(item) >= 2:
            second_element = item[1]  
            last_letter = second_element[-1]  
            new_second_element = second_element[:-1]  
            new_lst.append([item[0], new_second_element, last_letter] + item[2:])  
        else:
            new_lst.append(item) 
    return new_lst


path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

browser=webdriver.Chrome()


url = "https://www.indat.info/indat/content.php"
browser.get(url)

browser.add_cookie({"name":"basis_session_id","value":"va","domain":"indat.info"})
browser.add_cookie({"name":"PHPSESSID","value":"we","domain":"www.indat.info"})
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(20)

html = browser.page_source
```